# nmap and svnlib_client not working together

Tags: svn, debian, nmap

I installed nmap on Debian 6 squeeze, 64 bit. When I run nmap it says:

> nmap: error while loading shared libraries: libsvn_client-1.so.0: cannot open shared object >file: No such file or directory

so I googled it and found a solution which was.

> ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsvn_client-1.so.1 /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.0

I did that. but I'm still getting the same problem. It created the link successfully but it says nmap is still giving me the same error. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nmap shouldn't be linked to `libsvn_client`, but it can be if it was built with support for "nmap-update", an experimental way of updating Nmap Scripting Engine (NSE) scripts. Most people should not build in this feature since it requires an account, and there is currently no way to obtain an account.

To build Nmap without the nmap-update feature, you should `make clean`, then run `configure` with the `--without-nmap-update` flag, like so:

```
sh-$ ./configure --without-nmap-update
```

The reason why the `ln` command didn't fix your problem is that it created a symlink to the wrong version of libsvn_client. The binary is looking for version 0, and you linked version 1. It won't have the same symbols and interfaces.

Comment: I have all the libsvn files that I need. plus I didn't compile it. I used alien to convert it to to .deb then I used dpkg to install it.

Comment: I didn't read your question properly, since I didn't see the library version mismatch. Please see my edit to the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Ok I saw your edit, and I typed in: ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsvn_client-1.so.0 /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.0. I changed the 1 to a 0. but I'm still getting the same error. I've always set up nmap using .deb on my other systems, and I've never come across this problem before.

Comment: Well, it's unlikely that you already have both versions of the library. Check which one you have, then check what Nmap expects with `ldd`. If there's a mismatch, then you need to install the right version or get an Nmap binary that's linked against the right version or not compiled with nmap-update support.

Comment: Thanks for yall's help, but I figured it out. The problem was when I did "ln" I used "sudo", and because of that the "ln" was appended to libsvn like so: "libsvn_client-0.so.0ln" and that's why it wasn't finding the file, lol. And I found this by complete accident and stumbled on an article about the pros/cons of using sudo. And on that list was this: that sometimes sudo will append certain commands to the end of the file like in my case appending "ln" to libsvn.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is solved very easy, open synaptic and download the required version of libsvn (mine wished libsvn1)

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsvn_client-1.so.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsvn_client-1.so.0
```

... and it worked.  It seemed the original command

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsvn_client-1.so.0 /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.0
```

... that I have seen is missing the one part in the second root.

Answer (score 0):

installing subversion solved this problem for me in SUSE

```
#zypper in subversion
```

or in Debian:

```
#apt-get install subversion
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dnf install subversion -y` solved the problem in Fedora 32